# How to overwrite the existing document with different file and metadata?

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I've uploaded a document to SharePoint from code and along with a couple of list item properties. I can see the document successfully uploaded with item column values.

In the next step, I will upload a different document with some edited list item metadata. Now my question is it possible to overwrite the existing document in a  with the different file content?

My target is to overwrite the file with different file and list item metadata.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with files in SharePoint, if you upload a different document but giving it the same name as the previous one, SharePoint will think it's the same document, creating a new version.

Comment: Is it possible to replace that file with a new file with the different name?

Comment: I don't think so, the FileLeafRef is the key.